# Use in-memory SQLite in Laravel PHPUnit test

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpunit, laravel-5.6, in-memory-database

I'm trying to get a Laravel project running at my new work. The developer who left didn't specify how to get the code up and running in the handover document and no-one else knows either.

The SQLite database is created with `:memory:`, and `php artisan migrate` works without errors.

```
...
Migrating: 2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table
Migrated:  2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table
...
```

The method `beginDatabaseTransaction()` in the trait (standard Laravel code) is being executed, but none of the tables exist afterwards. It's as if the database is being created but the migration is not being executed.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Testing;

trait DatabaseTransactions
{
    /**
     * Handle database transactions on the specified connections.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beginDatabaseTransaction()
    {
        $database = $this->app->make('db');

        foreach ($this->connectionsToTransact() as $name) {
            $database->connection($name)->beginTransaction();
        }

        $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () use ($database) {
            foreach ($this->connectionsToTransact() as $name) {
                $connection = $database->connection($name);

                $connection->rollBack();
                $connection->disconnect();
            }
        });
    }
```

Test code (the last shown instruction fails):

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Feature;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository;

class PassportTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function test_basic_oauth_token_authentication(){
      $clientRepository = new ClientRepository();
      $client = $clientRepository->createPersonalAccessClient(
          null, 'Test Personal Access Client', $this->baseUrl
      );
```

Command line:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/PassPortTest
```

Error message:

> ```
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: oauth_clients
> Caused by  
> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: oauth_clients
> Caused by
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: oauth_clients
> ```

How can I ensure that the tables have been created as part of each test?

Comment: Try calling artisan migrate in the setUp function

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Another site suggested calling `Artisan::call('migrate');` as the first thing in th test, but that had no effect.

Comment: Is there anything extra going on in the `TestCase` class?

Comment: Use `RefreshDatabase` trait. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: @DigitalDrifter OK. Using `RefreshDatabase` _instead_ of `DatabaseTransactions` gets me past that error (to an unrelated error). Trying to`use` both gives a PHP error due to conflicting method names.

Comment: RefreshDatabase replaces DatabaseTransactions.  You shouldn't bother with transactions for in-memory databases.

Comment: @Devon Obviously that makes sense, but I'm dealing with someone else's code, and they're no longer around to explain their code.

Comment: @CJDennis  Right.. but as I said, RefreshDatabase replaces DatabaseTransactions, so you don't need that person around.  Just replace their usages of DatabaseTransactions with RefreshDatabase if you're using an in-memory database.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter It's specifically referring to not using transactions.  RefreshDatabase will use migrations if you have an in-memory database.

Comment: I meant DatabaseMigrations, not DatabaseTransactions. My mistake there. You are correct in your previous comment.

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of using the sqlite database for testing the the database / tables are removed after running the tests? I don't see why `php artisan migrate` should help here. Can you add your phpunit configuration file (xml)? Maybe you are missing a .env.testing file - might depend on the config / setup

Comment: @FrankProvost The point of `php artisan migrate` is to demonstrate that there are no errors in the schema (which there were initially), and that the `oauth_clients` table is included.

Comment: if your test environment is using a different database than your default env then it only shows that php artisan migrate is running for your default database. sqlite / h2  database might have minor differences or as said you're maybe just missing configuration

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? Yours is the only suggestion that worked.

Comment: @CJDennis Sure, I've put it into an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `RefreshDatabase` trait instead of the `DatabaseTransactions` trait (they have conflicts if you try to use both in the same class).

See the documents about [resetting the database after each test](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test).

Answer (score 1):

There's a caveat when using `:memory:` in your SQLite config.  The memory location that your command-line migrations are hitting is *not* the same one that the test is attempting to talk to.  Each instance of your app basically spins up a new virtual temporary database.

You have two options.  Either replace the `:memory:` config with an explicit filename, or make your test's `setUp()` method actually initiate the `\Aritsan::call('migrate')` call.  I wouldn't recommend the latter though, just because it could be slow, and I'm not entirely certain the migrations would actually stick if you have Transactions active at the time.